# When to use Kernel#gsub in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, kernel, gsub

I mostly use [`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) . I am familiar with it also. There is another [`Kernel#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gsub) which I have never used.

I tried to explore this as below :

```
(arup~>~)$ echo 'matz' | ruby -n -e 'puts $_.gsub(/./,"*")'
****
(arup~>~)$ echo 'matz' | ruby -n -e '$_.gsub(/./,"*") ; puts $_'
matz
(arup~>~)$ echo 'matz' | ruby -np -e '$_.gsub(/./,"*")'
matz
```

Docs is saying - *Equivalent to `$_.gsub`, except that `$_` will be updated if substitution occurs.* But in my case, it seems `$_` has not been updated.

The reason is `String#gsub` has been called. Not `Kernel#gsub`. See below :

```
(arup~>~)$ echo 'matz' | ruby -n -e 'p $_.method(:gsub)'
#<Method: String#gsub>
```

- How to call `Kernel#gsub` ?
- Why we need this method, while we have `String#gsub` ?

The same question I asked in [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4483353#new), but didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same examples you used above this should illustrate the point:

Using Kernel.gsub

```
echo 'matz' | ruby -np -e 'puts "before: " + $_; Kernel.gsub(/./,"*"); puts "after: " + $_'
# -> before: matz
# -> after: ****
```

and using $_.gsub

```
echo 'matz' | ruby -np -e 'puts "before: " + $_; $_.gsub(/./,"*"); puts "after: " + $_'
# -> before: matz
# -> after: matz
```

As you can See `$_` is only updated when using Kernel.gsub

### edit:

Some additional info, sprinkled with a little assumption on my end

Taken from [ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/English.rb#L34) the descriptive alias for `$_` is `$LAST_READ_LINE`. This is what the inline comments where the alias is created say:

> The last line read by Kernel.gets or
>     Kernel.readline. Many string-related functions in the
>     +Kernel+ module operate on $_ by default. The variable is 
>     local to the current scope. Thread local.

Now according to the c code for what ends up being made available as Kernel#gsub (defined in string.c)

```
static VALUE
rb_f_gsub(int argc, VALUE *argv)
{
  VALUE str = rb_funcall_passing_block(uscore_get(), rb_intern("gsub"), argc, argv);
  rb_lastline_set(str);
  return str;
}
```

This code uses the internal gsub method on a string and then explicity assigns `$_` to the new value before returning the mutated string itself.

The only reason I can come up with is that Kernel#gsub would have been used internally for some kind of pre-sanitization of input that would *always* occur. As a convenience method of sorts, immediately assigning the sanitized value to `$_` for further use without having to explicitly assign and return `$_`.

I'm saying *would have been* because it turns out that the changelog for ruby 1.9.1 lists `Kernel#gsub` as deprecated

> - Deprecation
>
> > o Kernel#getc, #gsub, #sub

The usage for `Kernel#gsub` in c is `rb_intern("gsub")` and I can't actually find any reference to it being used at all in the source of

- 1.8.7p371
- 1.8.0
- 1.7.1
- 1.6.0
- 1.3.1
- 1.0.0

I must be missing something here, the source for `rb_f_gsub` changed and was actually moved from `string.c` in 1.8.7 to `ruby.c` in 1.9.3, somewhere in between.

With all this, I think, we can answer the original question of *why we need it* - I guess we don't, not anymore at least.

So the question now becomes, when was it ever actually used and how?